# Row position in MySQL

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I was looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql), but can't find the answer to my question.

Need to get a list of objects from MySQL, for e.g.:

```
+-----------------------------+
+ id | username | password    +
+-----------------------------+
+  1 | User1                  +
+  2 | User2                  +
+  5 | User3                  +
+  9 | User4                  +
+ 11 | User5                  +
+ 18 | User6                  +
+ .....                       +
+ 25 | User10                 +
+-----------------------------+
```

and count the position oh each item, not the id, but the position where item is at this moment, all this with pagination, for e.g.:

```
Page 1
1, User1, id1
2, User2, id2
3, User3, id5

Page 2
4, User4, id9
5, User5, id11
6, User6, id18

Page 3
...
```

I understand that he must calculate the position of each item in the page list on every change of the page but don't know how to do this in MySQL.

I will highly appreciate if someone will help me with an advice. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by defining a variable in your SELECT request

```
SET @i=0;
SELECT id, username, password, @i:=@i+1 AS i FROM my_table ORDER BY id;
```

Comment: Can't get any result, the output is: Error executing query.

Comment: I edited my code, try the edited version with SET @i=0; instead of SELECT @i:=0; (But both should work i just tried it live on my server. can you paste your query ?)

Comment: The same output :)    SET @i=0;
SELECT id, member_name, @i:=@i+1 AS i FROM members ORDER BY id;

Comment: Where do you execute your query ? In the mysql console or in your java code ? If in java this may be the issue (i dont know how hibernate works but it may parse your query before sending it to mysql and remove the var), you may have to do a stored procedure to achieve this, if you want to compute the pagination in mysql

Comment: I do execute it in the MySQL Query Browser for now

Answer (score -1):

by using a variable during ***select query*** you can get the row position. this is working on my DB. you can use this.

```
set @i = 0;
SELECT id, firstname, lastname, title, @i := @i +1 as i FROM employee ORDER BY id
```